# Cannot use bcryptjs in boilerplate

Tags: electron, cryptography, boilerplate, bcryptjs

I am trying to use 'bcryptjs' in my 'boilerPlate' project but I am getting this warning. I tried adding 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }' to '.erb/configs/webpack.config.main.prod.ts', 'webpack.config.renderer . prod.ts" and rebuilt my project but it didn't work. Also, I am using bcryptjs in the rendering process.`

Compiled with problems:

WARNING in ./node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js 70:23-55

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/usename/Desktop/project-name/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }